# Oracle Pipelined Table Functions

Tags: function, plsql, pipeline

I try to call pipelined table function on other server by dblink, but get error

> "ORA-30626: function/procedure parameters of remote object types are not supported".

Maybe exist some way, how i can execute this function? All works, when not remote.

My query:

```
select * from table(DP.testpipe@DB_DCPRF_WSTAT)
```

Comment: Cleaned up wording and display of error.

Comment: what you means?

Comment: Just that I adjusted the language to be easier to read, as well as set the error to be more immediately visible.  I hoped to make this a better question, giving you a better chance for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to wrap it in a view.

Remote side:

```
create or replace view vv
as
select * from table(dp.testpipe());
```

Local:

```
select * from vv@DB_DCPRF_WSTAT;
```

Passing parameters may get tricky depending on your requirement.

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6020795600346824518

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I'm passing in function parameters.

Comment: The asktom page I linked to suggests using application contexts for that.